# Facebook login on android react-native

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

Im using [react-native-facebook-login](https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login) pacakge.

And following their instructions. But get undefined when I instantiate it.
Not sure what else I need to do here.

My init code is exactly as they have on the github.

```
  var FBLogin = require('react-native-facebook-login');
  var FBLoginManager = require('NativeModules').FBLoginManager;
```

But FBLoginManager always returns undefined.

Do I need to build a NativeModule named FBLoginManager for android??  Is there something Im missing? Or some java file, or Manifest.xml entry I need?

Also, when I look inside the react-native-facebook-login package.  I see two java files in the android part

```
     FacebookLoginModule.java
     FacebookLoginPackage.java
```

Should I be referring to these packages instead in react-native like so..?

```
 var FBLoginManager = require('NativeModules').FacebookLoginModule;
```

Or do they export the FBLoginManager as a function?

According to 2 people now, they were able to run the github example directly without any problems.

Comment: Try this : `var {NativeModules} = require('react-native');`
Then  `var FBLoginManager = NativeModules.FBLoginManager`
Does it still return `undefined` ?

Comment: Yeah...too bad in this case its not such an obvious mistake.  Although at this point, if I found out it was a typo or dumb error. I'd destroy my computer. lol

Comment: I actually encountered this error trying to use the module on its own without `react-native-facebook-login`. Once I added the proper code for that library to `MainActivity.java`, `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle`, the problem vanished. Might be silly to ask, but have you added the requisite code to the aforementioned files?

Comment: No I haven't because the instructions don't mention that at all.  Although just looking at the code its pretty obvious that I had to do something on Android side.  So what did you add to MainActivity.java?

Answer (score -1):

You must add some code to your Android project per instruction: https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login/blob/master/android/README.md